# IAM permissions for root user in AWS aurora RDS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora

I have an aurora instance with IAM authentication enabled
I have create an IAM role with full access to rds:*

when using that IAM role and trying to connect with the root user following these [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.AuthToken.Connect)

I get an error , `Access denied for user 'root'@'ip' (using password: YES)`

1. Why is there `using password:YES` when I'm using IAM auth
2. Should I be adding rds-db [permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html) explicitly  to the root user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on this , what I ended up doing :

1. Created a user using root user password authentication  following these [instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/)
2. For the user I created I gave the following IAM creds : `rds-db:connect`